# Keep getting this error 'post' object has no attribute 'liked_by_set'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I keep getting this error 'post' object has no attribute 'liked_by_set'

```
Models.py 
liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likedby')

views.py 

def like_unlike_article(request, post_id):
    a = post.objects.get(id=post_id) 
    user = request.user

    if user is a.liked_by_set.all():
        # User has liked it before, means he wants to unlike it
        a.liked_by_set.remove(user) # remove him from ``liked_by`` set
        a.likes -= 1 # unlike the article
    else:
        # User wants to like it
        a.liked_by_set.add(user) # add him to ``liked_by`` set
        a.likes += 1 # like the article

    a.save()
```

Any help?

Comment: You have to show us your models in order to get an answer to this question.

Comment: I think .all() return a list, then `if user in a.liked_by.all(): a.liked_by.remove(user)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the 'liked_by' instead of 'liked_by_set':

```
a.liked_by.all()
```

Also note that `user is a.liked_by_set.all()` will always return `False`.  Use the `in` clause:

```
if user in a.liked_by.all():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can fix this.

```
class Post:
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likedby')
```

This will make the following possible

```
a = post.objects.get(id=post_id)
a.liked_by.all() # [<User: 1>, <User: 2>] 

or

user = request.user
user.liked_by_set.all() # [<Post: 1>, <Post: 2>]
```

I would create the following statement

```
if a.liked_by.get(id=user.id):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

or

```
if user.liked_by_set.get(id=post_id):
    ...
else:
    ...
```